# AMPscript to show copy dynamically

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm trying to write a bit of AMPscript that does the following:

IF firstname exists say "John, your"

IF no firstname say "Your"

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
%%=iif(empty(@firstName),"Your", concat(propercase(@firstName, "your")))=%%
```

I know it's a simple answer, help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple issues with it, but were 90% of the way there. (Assuming you have `@firstName` correctly defined above this snippet of course)

`%%=iif(empty(@firstName),"Your", concat(propercase(@firstName, "your")))=%%`

should be:
`%%=iif(empty(@firstName),"Your", concat(propercase(@firstName), ", your"))=%%`

The difference being:
 1. altering the propercase to only go around `@firstName` so that the 'your' does not become capitalized as well.
 2. Adding a comma and a space (', ') to your concat string value so it shows `John, your` instead of `Johnyour`

That is pretty much it! Like I said, you were 90% of the way there! Great Job.

I saw your comment on another answer asking about setting FirstName if that does not exist in the Sendable data.  See below for best practice to handle this:

`SET @firstName = AttributeValue("firstName")`
Utilizing AttributeValue will allow a null value for `@firstName` if the field does not exist, instead of causing an error like the raw personalization string would (`SET @firstName = firstName`)

---

Final block would be:

```
%%[ 
VAR @firstName
SET @firstName = AttributeValue("firstName")
]%%

%%=iif(empty(@firstName),"Your", concat(propercase(@firstName), ", your"))=%%
```

Assuming firstName field in the sending DE is `John`, the output would be:
`John, your`
and if firstName is empty or field does not exist, output would be:
`Your`

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

I do already have Attribute Value in there however.

I have this:
%%[var /*@firstName*/
set /*@firstName*/ = AttributeValue("firstName")]%%

With your previously supplied AMPscript as the actual dynamic copy.

Have I implemented it incorrectly somewhere?

Comment: ...you'll see that I failed to effectively comment out the AMPscipt - but you get the idea!

Comment: Correct. I am going to edit my answer to show it fully implemented.

Comment: Great, thank you.  That worked.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
%%[

set @firstName = AttributeValue("firstName")
set @your = Iif(not Empty(@firstName), Concat(ProperCase(@firstName), ", your"), "Your")

]%%

%%=v(@your)=%%
```

Reference:

- [Iif](https://ampscript.guide/iif/)
- [Concat](https://ampscript.guide/concat/)
- [ProperCase](https://ampscript.guide/propercase/)

**EDIT**

If the field does not exist in the sendable Data Extension, it will render as the fallback version, in this case “Your”.

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume you've SET @FirstName correctly.

I would try it a little differently...maybe not as slick but:

`%%[ IF @FirstName is null THEN ]%% Your
 %%[ELSE]%% %%=ProperCase(@FirstName)=%%, your
 %%[ENDIF]%%`

OR

`%%[ IF Empty(AttributeValue("FirstName")) THEN ]%% Your
 %%[ELSE]%% %%=ProperCase(@FirstName)=%%, your
 %%[ENDIF]%%`

Comment: Thank you, this worked.  However, I've also come across another scenario.  What if there is no Firstname column at all in the Data Extension, how would I account for that as well?

Comment: @ThomasHockey - I edited my answer to provide information on how to handle your comment above.